# Magento 2.3 Slow Site Speed / Mobile Speed / Search

Tags: magento2.3, pagespeed, litespeed

Greetings Stack Community,
we have been having site speed issues ever since switching to Magento 2, much worse on mobile devices. https://onthegolinens.com/
Here are the specs:

1. http://onthegolinens.com/phpinfo.php
2. Litespeed with LiteMage Cache installed
3. 4000+ Products, MagePlaza Search
4. [image: Server Information]

What do we need to do to make this site load faster and properly? It appears almost unusable.
Flat Catalog on/off?
Best search configuration?
Modules/Settings missed?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can implement if not already implemented to optimise the speed of your Magento 2 website and achieve better performance.

- Use a fast hosting provider.
- Activate the OpCache module.
- Use redis cache for session storage.
- Enable GZIP compression.
- Disable not-required modules.
- Enable production mode.
- Enable varnish full page cache.
- Enable CSS, JS and html minification.
- Enable JS and CSS merging. - Do not use JS bundling
- Use CDN for static content deployment
- Minimize TTFB
- Add Expires Headers.
- Debug response time for each custom module/function/api and check if it can be optimized..
- Use css sprites to combine images.
- Remove js/css comments to improve code performance.
- Optimize image sizes. Do not use heavy weight images.
- Use elasticsearch for search purpose.
- Split the database.
- Perform third-party extension audit.
- Optimize poorly written code.
- Use an Image LazyLoader.
- Clean log tables (like report_event, report_viewed_product_index, customer_visitor, etc)
- Update Magento to latest version.
- Reduce number of DOM elements on the site.
- Debug if there are any events which can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A couple more to add to the list from above after looking at your site:

- Upgrade PHP from 7.1 (deprecated) to 7.4
- Make sure you're operating in PRODUCTION mode
- Merge and Minify your CSS files
- Minify your JS files
- Check that Litemage is ENABLED.  You'll need to go into the admin gui and verify this.  I'm not seeing the LITESPEED headers such as:

  X-LiteSpeed-Cache: miss, litemage
  X-LiteSpeed-Cache-Control:public,max-age=1800
  X-LiteSpeed-Tag:B1_F,B1_

Litemage should give you a TTFB of less than 100ms without a CDN.

Follow this: https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/litemage/

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 is one of the fastest pretty high scoring if delivered properly( expensive for most developers and website owners to spend those extra efforts to get rid of unwanted JS):

Suggestions :

1. Varnish : A must have
2. Lazy loading
3. Responsive images
4. Critical css or online css for above fold content.
5. Minimiza JS for above fold content
6. RequireJS and advance JS Bundle recommended.
7. disable not used modules.
8. Remove unused JS
9. Use CDN to reduce hop time
10. webP or next generation images are a must.
11. Evaluate modules installed as they might add up to your JS payload.
12. Avoid fonts unless its a must
13. Analyse modules used and there impact and either remove or replace.
14. use elastic search to reduce Mysql load.
15. Look at average page time rather then just checking one specific page score( google analytics will give you that insight).
    16.To reduce Total blocking time replace JS code by css where ever possible.
    17.build over a light weight theme as it had been seen that when a theme comes with lots of features they also come with the issue of lower speed on GSI specially for Mobile.
16. Reduce JS in head and use differ or async.
17. use GTM
18. On times some media are downloaded but never displayed so take care of this aspect as well.
19. Image size to be taken care.
20. Upgrade PHP version.
21. Upgrade Magento version
22. Check what's displayed above fold and just reduce html,css thats used for displays on click like menu and fetch them after document ready event.
    Note : If all done properly a score of above 85 on desktop for product page on GSI can be achieved and maintained.